# How to quickly determine if part of a string matches another string?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have address lists that sometimes have junk at the end of the street suffix that needs to be removed. For example Yada Yada St. apt#12 needs to become Yada Yada St. Now, I have found a list of street suffixes and their variations from [here](https://www.usps.com/send/official-abbreviations.htm#T).  I need to do this all in excel so I put the 3 column list of suffixes (columns 1-3 being Primary Street Suffix,    Commonly Used Street Suffix or Abbreviation, and Postal Service Standard Suffix Abbreviation respectively) into a worksheet labeled SuffixList and I put the address list into sheet 1 which is where the code is.

I created a code to check each address against each suffix variation (column 2 on SuffixList) using a space before and after the suffix I'm checking to make sure I'm not catching any street names, just the street suffixes. I also have the . and , variations being checked in the code as you can see below. The code I'm using now works, it just takes too long and I'm looking for a faster method.

Also, any time I find a match, I am replacing the street suffix used with the officially correct one (column 3 on suffix list).

Current Code:

```
Sub JunkRemover()
    'Link to an official abbreviations list
    'https://www.usps.com/send/official-abbreviations.htm

    Dim Orig As String
    Dim NewAddr As String
    Dim x As Integer 'Row Reference
    Dim i As Long 'Address List Iterator
    Dim y As Integer 'SuffixList Iterator
    Dim ChangeCount As Integer
    'WARNING!!!!!!!!!!!!
    'This code assumes address field is in column A and that the address column has no blanks.
    'If that is not the case, replace 1 for the appropriate number for x
    'a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4 etc.
    x = 1

    ChangeCount = 0
    i = 2
    While Cells(i, x) <> ""
        Orig = UCase(Cells(i, x))
        y = 2
        While Sheets("SuffixList").Cells(y, 2) <> ""

            If InStr(1, Orig, " " & UCase(Sheets("SuffixList").Cells(y, 2) & " ")) > 1 Then
               NewAddr = Left(Orig, InStr(1, Orig, " " & UCase(Sheets("SuffixList").Cells(y, 3) & " ")) + Len(Sheets("SuffixList").Cells(y, 3)))
               Cells(i, x) = NewAddr
               ChangeCount = ChangeCount + 1
            ElseIf InStr(1, Orig, " " & UCase(Sheets("SuffixList").Cells(y, 2) & ". ")) > 1 Then
               NewAddr = Left(Orig, InStr(1, Orig, " " & UCase(Sheets("SuffixList").Cells(y, 3) & ". ")) + Len(Sheets("SuffixList").Cells(y, 3)))
               Cells(i, x) = NewAddr
               ChangeCount = ChangeCount + 1
            ElseIf InStr(1, Orig, " " & UCase(Sheets("SuffixList").Cells(y, 2) & ", ")) > 1 Then
               NewAddr = Left(Orig, InStr(1, Orig, " " & UCase(Sheets("SuffixList").Cells(y, 3) & ", ")) + Len(Sheets("SuffixList").Cells(y, 3)))
               Cells(i, x) = NewAddr
               ChangeCount = ChangeCount + 1
            End If
        y = y + 1
        Wend

    i = i + 1
    Wend

    MsgBox ChangeCount & " Rows Changed", vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Further Examples:

```
OrigAddress                   NewAddress  
4000 NO MAIN ST 1             4000 NO MAIN ST    
135 ALDEN ST APT3             135 ALDEN ST   
1820 HIGHLAND AVE             1820 HIGHLAND AVE   
4901 NO MAIN ST. REAR         4901 NO MAIN ST   
1820 HIGHLAND AVE, 1          1820 HIGHLAND AVE
```

Final Code users Potter's answer:

```
Sub JunkRemover2()
    'Link to an official abbreviations list
    'https://www.usps.com/send/official-abbreviations.htm

    Dim Orig As String
    Dim NewAddr As String
    Dim x As Integer 'Row Reference
    Dim i As Long 'Address List Iterator
    Dim y As Integer 'SuffixList Iterator
    Dim ChangeCount As Integer
    Dim PauseTime, Start, Finish, TotalTime As Double
    Dim slRows As Double
    Dim slCols As Integer
    Dim slRowsAddr As Double
    Dim slColsAddr As Integer

    'WARNING!!!!!!!!!!!!
    'This code assumes address field is in column A and that the address column has no blanks.
    'If that is not the case, replace 1 for the appropriate number for x
    'a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4 etc.
    x = 1

    ChangeCount = 0

    With Sheets("SuffixList")
      'i am using Column 1 to find out how many rows there are(change it if you want)
       slRows = Sheets("SuffixList").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
       slCols = Sheets("SuffixList").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
       suffixData = Sheets("SuffixList").Range(Sheets("SuffixList").Cells(2, 2), Sheets("SuffixList").Cells(slRows, slCols))
    End With


    i = 2
    While Cells(i, x) <> ""
        Orig = UCase(Cells(i, x))

        For y = 1 To slRows - 1


            If InStr(1, Orig, " " & UCase(suffixData(y, 1) & " ")) > 1 Then
               NewAddr = Left(Orig, InStr(1, Orig, " " & UCase(suffixData(y, 2) & " ")) + Len(suffixData(y, 2)))
               Cells(i, x) = NewAddr
               ChangeCount = ChangeCount + 1
               Exit For
            ElseIf InStr(1, Orig, " " & UCase(suffixData(y, 1) & ". ")) > 1 Then
               NewAddr = Left(Orig, InStr(1, Orig, " " & UCase(suffixData(y, 2) & ". ")) + Len(suffixData(y, 2)))
               Cells(i, x) = NewAddr
               ChangeCount = ChangeCount + 1
               Exit For
            ElseIf InStr(1, Orig, " " & UCase(suffixData(y, 1) & ", ")) > 1 Then
               NewAddr = Left(Orig, InStr(1, Orig, " " & UCase(suffixData(y, 2) & ", ")) + Len(suffixData(y, 2)))
               Cells(i, x) = NewAddr
               ChangeCount = ChangeCount + 1
               Exit For
            End If
        Next

    i = i + 1
    Wend


    MsgBox ChangeCount & " Rows Changed", vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Comment: a faster method would be to use formulas to get the data you want. Can you tell us how your worksheets are setup, what columns are used, and what column do you want the suffix, and what column do you want the address?

Comment: I don't see in your code what you are doing with the value of **NewAddr** inside your loop.

Comment: Address is all in one column in sheet 1 and in this case column 1. Full suffix list being referenced is as described above.

Comment: can you post an example of the address before, and the suffix to change, and the result afterwards.

Comment: Added more examples of addresses before and after code runs. Suffix list being referenced is on the linked website. Just click on the street suffixes tab and as described above, I'm checking for the suffixes in the middle column and replacing them with the rightmost column.

Comment: i think you should use Split on your full address column ( space as delimiter ), then if array(1), array(2), array(3) is equal or contains your suffixes then stick it in your 3rd column. what you are doing above is not really an efficient solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right; it is slow because every time you compare stuff you access the Excel application, which is considerably slower than just accessing, say, a variable.

I would suggest you copy the relevant fields you want to arrays like so:

```
    dim suffixData as variant

    'Now you need to save all that sheets' content into an array
    '1stly you need the sheet's dimentions

      dim slRows as double
      dim slCols as integer
      'I am using Column 1 to find out how many rows there are(change it if you want)

   with Sheets("SuffixList")
       slRows = .Cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlUp).row
       slCols = .Cells(1, columns.count).end(xlToLeft).column
       suffixData = .Range(.cells(1,1), .cells(slRows, slCols))
    end with
```

From here onwards you should use `suffixData(row, column)` to access that sheet as if it was the actual sheet. On a thousand+ iterations on it you will see a definite improvements.

You can do the same trick with the other sheets and calculate everything without even looking up Excel while you do your costly loops.

The reverse is also advisable. You don't want to write to a cell each time you have its value.
It's much better to write it to a 2D array as if it was the spreadsheet and then copy the entire array to the sheet.

Comment: Worked great thank you. reduced run time for 19827 addresses to be checked from 378 seconds to 23 seconds. I will also think about implementing arrays for the addresses and result set.

Comment: The benefit of using With Sheets("SuffixList") is that you can leave that prefix before writing so instead of writing "Sheets("SuffixList").Cells....." you can write ".Cells...". Just a tip to keep your code cleaner :)